# Align vertical rotated text with horizontal text

Tags: html, css

I'm playing with some vertical text as a span within a heading element.  The problem is I can't figure out how to eliminate the space that's created between the vertical span and the rest of the text content.

Looking at the fiddle, I'm looking to tuck "We're Just A" right up next to the S in Small and the "Striving For A" right next to the 'B' in Big Feel.

**What it looks like now:**
[image: Non-working version]

**What I'm looking to do**
[image: the goal]

**The HTML:**

```
<h2>
 <span class="smallVertical orangeText">We're Just A</span>
 Small<br/>Company<br/>
 <span class="smallVertical">Striving For A</span>
 <span class="orangeText">Big Feel</span>
</h2>
```

The CSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald';

h2 {
  text-align:right;
  font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:8em;
  line-height:1.1em;
}

h2 span.smallVertical {
  font-size:12%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  float:left;
}

h2 span.orangeText {
  color:#FF9900;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/jf5kwh3t/)

So basically: How to eliminate the horizontal space between rotated and non-rotated text using CSS?

Comment: Put the each span and following line of text in a div tag, position that absolute right, position the span absolute left.

Comment: I'll post an example shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite **hard** and seems like you need some real help here :)
I'll try to explain in code:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald';

h2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 8em;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

h2 span.smallVertical {
  font-size: 12%;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  
  /*float: left;                 /* NOOOOOOOOOOOO :) */
  display: inline-block;         /* use this instead of float:left */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(50%); /* Add: translateY 50% */
  width: 8em;                    /* same as font size (OR A BIT SMALLER) */
  text-align:center;             /* to center text inside the red thing */
  vertical-align:top;            /* top to "center" span... (yeah I know...) */
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);  /* just to see what the heck we're doing */
  white-space: nowrap;           /* prevent small text wrap at 8em */
}

h2 span.orangeText {
  color: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span class="smallVertical orangeText">We're Just A</span>
  Small<br/>Company<br/>
  <span class="smallVertical">Striving For A</span>
  <span class="orangeText">Big Feel</span>
</h2>
```

***Tip-of-tha-day***: By adding `white-space: nowrap;` you can even make the text exceed the famous `8em` and still make it nicely and typographically  aligned at the baseline as in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jf5kwh3t/8/

To make all small text aligned ***"baseline"*** (like in the jsFiddle's demo last line) simply use
`text-align: left;`.

Comment: My first thoughts were that this is better than my solution, but it's not with out its faults. The text can break between the vertical line of text and the large text (maybe a `nbsp;` would work?). And the type doesn't line top and bottom, it looks to be centred? I also have issues there.

Comment: @Sarcoma I don't see any issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/jf5kwh3t/9/ . Can you shed some light?

Comment: Inline blocks do seem much more appropriate, and I can see this being much more flexible in terms of responsive design.

Comment: @Sarcoma OK thanks, but you mentiones some issues... Can you edit my fiddle to explain which case creates one?

Comment: Maybe it's just on iPhone but the vertical text isn't quite flush top and bottom and if the width is reduced the large word breaks to a new line.

Comment: @Sarcoma heheh me too :) thanks BTW, I don't have any iphone but on android looks just like on windows 10 Chrome latest (without the vendor -webkit- etc prefixes for `transform`..)

Comment: Ignore the first part it actually matches the design!

Comment: Thanks @Roko!  Exactly what I needed and I appreciate you taking the time to comment the code.  @Sarcoma - you're absolutely right with it not being flush.  I just quickly threw those images together to help with the question.  I'll likely go back and add individual classes to each span to either increase the font size or letter spacing to get that flush.  You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask, but also maintains the order of the text.

By wrapping the words in `div` tags we can position the spans to the left of them with absolute positioning.

HTML:

```
<h2>
<div class="top">
    <span class="smallVertical orangeText">We're Just A</span>
    Small
</div>
<div class="mid">
  Company
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <span class="smallVertical">Striving For A</span>
    <span class="orangeText">Big Feel</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald';
h2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 8em;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}

h2 div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
}

.mid {
    top: 135px;
}

.bottom {
    top: 270px;
}

h2 span.smallVertical {
    font-size: 12%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -66px;
}

.bottom .smallVertical {
    left: -76px
}

h2 span.orangeText {
    color: #FF9900;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jf5kwh3t/7/

Comment: That's **wrong** cause the distance between the text and the first big character is dictated by the small text length....

Comment: Yeah it's a tough one. Like I said I thought I had it, it is late though. I've not used rotated text like that before. I did wonder why the left margins were off.

Comment: Totally agree. I was also impressed at the additional CSS weight I needed to add in order to make this work (and handle all cases of small text length etc)